# Adding to a string array later with a method

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, listview

I'm currently making an app for a forum, I want to add a favorites feature where there is a list of different sections of the forums people can add to their favorites list for quick access to them.

I'm having one slight problem though, I'm using a listview for the list of their favorites, so I need to add a new value to the listview when the user adds a new section to their favorites.

So really all I need to know, is how can I add to my string array for my list view, with a button? Or can I have all the options in the array and then decide witch ones show up according to what the user has chosen?

Answer (score 1):

You could send an array of string with the current favourites to the list adapter. When more favourites are added, you can add them to the array and call

```
list.notfiyDataSetChanged();
```

This will update the list.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a large enough array to hold all the possible options you can use setVisibleRowCount(int) to change how many are visible based on how many items are currently in the array.

Comment: So are you saying that I put all of the options into the array at the start, then I can you setVisibleRowCount(int) inside a bunch of if statements to decide which ones show depending on which options they've picked? And replace int with the strings inside the array?

Comment: create a new array and copy it into the list array each time, but use setVisibleRowCount to limit the number of showing options

Comment: Sorry I'm not understanding it, I'll play around with it a little and see what I come up with.